# cant run react nginx on port 443 and 80 both are in used

Tags: centos, docker, nginx, node.js, vps

I have react, nodejs app and dockerize them.
frontend running with Nginx on port 80 and 443 on my local docker-machine.
when I run the docker-compose command on my VPS centos it throws an error that ports 80 and 443 are in use.

```
http            80/tcp          www www-http    # WorldWideWeb HTTP
http            80/udp          www www-http    # HyperText Transfer Protocol
http            80/sctp                         # HyperText Transfer Protocol
https           443/tcp                         # http protocol over TLS/SSL
https           443/udp                         # http protocol over TLS/SSL
https           443/sctp                        # http protocol over TLS/SSL
```

what should I do?

Comment: use different ports

Comment: I want to run a website so when someone enters my domain address I don't want them to add a port at the end  of the address is there a way to use different port and redirect request to port 443 of my server to nginx new port for ssl?

Comment: you want to use nginx as a reverse proxy to the port exposed on the dockerized app(s) - e.g. the docker could expose 12345 externally to 80 internally - so your app listens on 80 still - and nginx directs the appropriate traffic to localhost:12345